# react-native cross platform work on Android | Ios and web?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, web

i know that react-native allows to code in android and ios at the same time , but does it allow to code the web version ?

Exemple:

My application on android and ios is : test123

My application on a website is : test123.com

So I would like to know if I code in react-native, if there is also a web version to put it on a website?

> If yes :

1 - How to configure our react-native application with our website?

2-  How to test my application on my website while I code ?

> If no:

Is there a solution to quickly code in web version what we did with react-native?

Thank you!

Comment: have you tried ```react-native-web``` library? thats the official one to use it to create webistes with react native . https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web

Comment: It is work with a react-native application? Because i get an error like that :  `npm WARN react-native-web@0.12.0-rc.1 requires a peer of react-dom@>=16.5.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself`. And after i get a lot of error. I would send a picture put we can't in commentary. After, how to run the react-native application version web? To run ios or android i do :`react-native run-android` or `react-native run-ios` but, we can't do `react-native run-web`